# Python перевод hexadecimal str в hexadecimal int

Tags: python, ctypes

Функция `hex` возвращает тип данных строку, а нужно число. Использую библиотеку `ctypes`, требуется преобразовывать символы юникода в `ushort`

```
type(hex(ord('h'))) # -> str
type(0x68)          # -> int
```

Как я могу получить hex-число в типе int?

Comment: Это как? Число - это число. Оно представления как такового не имеет, пока вы его в строку в определённой системе счисления не превратите. `ord('h') == 0x68` ==> `True`.................................  `ctypes.c_ushort(0x68)` ==> `c_ushort(104)`......................`ctypes.c_ushort(ord('h'))` ==> `c_ushort(104)`

Comment: `ctypes.c_ushort(hex(123))` выдаст ошибку, так как hex возращает значения типа класса строки (`'0x01'`), а мне нужно получить `0x01`

Comment: Зачем вам передавать `hex(123)`? Передавайте `123`. Почему вы всё время пытаетесь передать строчку? Ещё раз: что вы напишете `ctypes.c_ushort(123)`, что `ctypes.c_ushort(0x7B)` -это одно и то же число.

Comment: это действительно так, но мне нужно симмулировать пользовательский ввод, а это значит мне нужно приводить к типу `ctypes.c_ushort()` буквы латиницы

Comment: Тогда вам, как приведено в ответе ниже, сначала нужно использовать `int('строка_в_hex', 16)` для преобразования в `int`.  `ctypes.c_ushort(int('0x7B', 16))` ==> `c_ushort(123)`................. `ctypes.c_ushort(int('7B', 16))` ==> `c_ushort(123)` А вообще в вопросе написали бы, что и как получаете на входе, и что и как хотите это собираетесь использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите перевести `0x123`в `291`. Если так, то

```py
>>> int('0x123', 16)
# 291
>>> int('0x123'[2:], 16)  # => int('123', 16)
# 291
```

Также, `ord -> int`:

```py
>>> ord('h')
104
```

Если же вы хотите просто работать с `'0x123'` как с `int` (складывать-умножать-вычитать), то приведите его к `int10` (или не переводите в `hex` :) ), а в, собственно, `hex` переводите только когда нужно куда-то передать значение в виде 16-числа.

Comment: мне нужно передать аргумент в формате `ctypes.ushort`, и при попытке передать условно `func('0x01')`, я получаю ошибку, мне нужно передать `func(0x01)`, где 0x01 - будет типа int